# How to keep two columns on top of each other and other column to the right in bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am just wondering if it's possible in flexbox (without javascript or positioning or css grid) to change the layout like this. On desktop
[image]
and on phone it should look like below
[image]
I am using bootstrap 4, and there is option to change order but even that is not able to fulfill the expectation.

i am able to achieve the functionality using float

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="float-none float-lg-left col-lg-6">1</div>
        <div class="float-none float-lg-right">2</div>
        <div class="float-none float-lg-left col-lg-6">3</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: i want the right column to come between the first and third on mobile phone

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far

Comment: could you post the code you've already tried?

Comment: yes check, updated the code

Comment: Why can't you make 2 rows? This is how it was intended to be done. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: cant use two rows as i have to keep the 2nd column in between the first and third on mobile phones.

Comment: also the second column is taking the combined height of column 1 & 3

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Taj Khan you can hide column-2 and show according to screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know i'm a bit late to the question, not entirely Bootstrap 4 flexbox either - but you can do this with `display:flex` and a media query. You just need to set a height on the parent (in this case `.wrapper`), so that boxes 1 and 3 are '50%' of this height.

View the snippet full screen to see the switch of the boxes:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 200px;
}

.box1 {
  background: #31d1d3;
}

.box2 {
  background: #bce9e2;
}

.box3 {
  background: #62b1b7;
}

@media screen and (min-width:797px) {
  .box2 {
    order: 3;
  }
  .box1,
  .box3 {
    flex: 0 0 50%;
    width: 50%;
  }
  .box2 {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box1">1</div>
    <div class="box2">2</div>
    <div class="box3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without CSS grid it is possible ***BUT*** Column 2 ***MUST*** be smaller than Column 1 and Column 3 combined.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {

    .wrapper {
        padding-right: 50%;
        position: relative;
    }

    .box--2 {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 50%;
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box">Column 1</div>
    <div class="box box--2">Column 2</div>
    <div class="box">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

The size of `.wrapper` would be calculated from the height of the elements in flow (Column 1 and Column 3). If Column 2 is taller than those two, it will overflow out of the wrapper and there's nothing you can do to fix that without JavaScript.

Honestly, using CSS Grid (with IE fallbacks) is the better solution.

Comment: I've clearly mentioned in the question without using positioning, and just for the knowledge second column height is greater than column 1 and 3

Comment: @TajKhan sorry, I missed that note. In that case: no, it's not possible

Comment: cool, thanks for the suggestion of css grid just wondering is it okay to use as i have to keep the compatibility till ie 10

Comment: @TajKhan IE10 and IE11 have a version of CSS Grid. It doesn't allow for things like named areas, but you can still define columns. https://caniuse.com/#search=grid